# Remove parentheses with text in Excel

Tags: excel, text, parentheses

I have a list of employee names.  Some names are in the format as

John Smith

Some names on the same list are listed as

Jane Smith (Terminated)

For the terminated names I need to remove the (Terminated) in excel.

How do I do this?

Comment: formula below works but added space makes vlookup N/A for terminated employees due to space after name.  Any idea how to remove space so name will be a match?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use the replace function:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C3,"(Terminated)","")
```

Where C3 is the cell that contains the text you want to modify.

Comment: You could make that an `If` statement, which would allow him to drag down an entire column (instead of just knowing which lines have "terminated"): `=If(Right(C3,1)=")",SUBSTITUTE(C3,"(Terminated)",""),C3)`

Comment: problem I am running into is that I am doing a vlookup from another tabbed spreadsheet. For the terminated employees the name is not being recognized because of the added space.  Any idea how to remove?

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(C3," (Terminated)","")`

Comment: Tim has the update you need. I forgot to grab the extra space in my statement.. :)

Comment: how about replacing any content within parentheses? ..any content not particularly 'Terminated'

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have `Formula` or `VBA` tags on your question, another way to do this is to use the `Find and Replace` functionality of Excel.

## 1

On the sheet where you wish to remove the parentheses with text, press Control-F on the keyboard.

## 2

When the dialog opens, click the Replace tab.

## 3

Type the following WITHOUT the quotation marks:

```
" (Terminated)"
```

Notice that there is a space character just before the first paren. Again, don't type the quotation marks.

## 4

Leave the `Replace with` field blank.

## 5

Click the `Replace All` button.